# Making sense of why and when polyline matches what is shown in Google Maps

Tags: qgis, line, google-maps, google-maps-api

By making Google Maps API call, I received a response JSON which contained this polyline1:

```
ezdvBcps}Lt@W@F@BVKl@UK]Wc@}@kAOKBEzA{BdA}Ab@s@LBf@RjARZBv@?rAAfBIX?f@FLBf@^b@hATbAF~@BvB?hALjBHpCLjAVdAd@dAxCbGlA~BbBvCpAbD`AnCVpB\\hBf@nB|@tAb@f@RVXLbDj@jCl@nAf@`DbBdC`B`@b@HNN`@lA~DnAvBvB`G\\fA^p@j@z@~E`FbBpBxDfFXh@|@pD`@bB^fANd@\\`Bl@rBb@fATj@v@bBjBwCd@w@NB^B\\@\\K\\Q|AWZGXOPIRBb@K\\Kl@_@VOZWVI^Eh@Ov@KxCJ\\@\\K^@RMh@QhAMXKXY`@Q^SLK`@]fBc@n@M\\OlB_@n@KNMRUZQZGh@Ht@Lx@F`@BTANDRNTPNDDHLXN`@LRTJx@?RBJFFLV\\Zs@TQ`@MVIhAYp@YPc@VgALk@Hk@d@eA\\cAHq@Eo@J}@@q@DItAgAv@i@|@e@v@k@bAaAdDuB|@c@?I?]?{@Ms@COFWJODYEcABOTU^e@H_@Km@Ci@BU?e@Ca@Ie@e@oBKk@Eu@M{@CoAC}@Km@Iy@IaA?{@Ci@Ms@UgA]y@Mm@GQICe@QKMGi@Gi@GSI[Ym@[{@@_AK]SMo@i@OCg@EOEMMYSi@IUO]Ko@KSIWUWMU_@I]Kw@WoACY@a@CWQWe@[QIOYMYW]SMQUQu@OWWSUWU[SsAEg@Ic@Mc@?a@Ai@Em@AUOa@M_@e@g@MSGYOY_@YIQSR[Pa@mBQaAI[@QDyACq@Iu@o@k@e@Y]IcAAmBC]Ee@IgAUWAw@Ae@GWSaAeAYk@Si@a@k@YAc@O{@]a@MnAqA~@mCVaAHk@YmCIQSQOS
```

## Rendering polyline1 directly

I tried to visualize this polyline using [online tool](https://open-polyline-decoder.60devs.com/), which gave me following output:

**Image 1:**

[image]

When I stored this polyline in postgres as `GEOMETRY(LINESTRING)` using `st_asText(ST_LineFromEncodedPolyline(...)` function (as explained in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/421322/199167)), QGIS rendered it exactly same as above.

## Polyline1 to lat-long array to polyline2 conversion and then rendering polyline2

I tried to decode the polyline into lat long array in Python using [`polyline`](https://pypi.org/project/polyline/) package ([github link](https://github.com/frederickjansen/polyline)).

```
>>> import polyline
>>> l = polyline.decode('ezdvBcps}Lt@W@F@BVKl@UK]Wc@}@kAOKBEzA{BdA}Ab@s@LBf@RjARZBv@?rAAfBIX?f@FLBf@^b@hATbAF~@BvB?hALjBHpCLjAVdAd@dAxCbGlA~BbBvCpAbD`AnCVpB\\hBf@nB|@tAb@f@RVXLbDj@jCl@nAf@`DbBdC`B`@b@HNN`@lA~DnAvBvB`G\\fA^p@j@z@~E`FbBpBxDfFXh@|@pD`@bB^fANd@\\`Bl@rBb@fATj@v@bBjBwCd@w@NB^B\\@\\K\\Q|AWZGXOPIRBb@K\\Kl@_@VOZWVI^Eh@Ov@KxCJ\\@\\K^@RMh@QhAMXKXY`@Q^SLK`@]fBc@n@M\\OlB_@n@KNMRUZQZGh@Ht@Lx@F`@BTANDRNTPNDDHLXN`@LRTJx@?RBJFFLV\\Zs@TQ`@MVIhAYp@YPc@VgALk@Hk@d@eA\\cAHq@Eo@J}@@q@DItAgAv@i@|@e@v@k@bAaAdDuB|@c@?I?]?{@Ms@COFWJODYEcABOTU^e@H_@Km@Ci@BU?e@Ca@Ie@e@oBKk@Eu@M{@CoAC}@Km@Iy@IaA?{@Ci@Ms@UgA]y@Mm@GQICe@QKMGi@Gi@GSI[Ym@[{@@_AK]SMo@i@OCg@EOEMMYSi@IUO]Ko@KSIWUWMU_@I]Kw@WoACY@a@CWQWe@[QIOYMYW]SMQUQu@OWWSUWU[SsAEg@Ic@Mc@?a@Ai@Em@AUOa@M_@e@g@MSGYOY_@YIQSR[Pa@mBQaAI[@QDyACq@Iu@o@k@e@Y]IcAAmBC]Ee@IgAUWAw@Ae@GWSaAeAYk@Si@a@k@YAc@O{@]a@MnAqA~@mCVaAHk@YmCIQSQOS')
>>> l[:5]
[(19.52691, 73.17778), (19.52664, 73.1779), (19.52663, 73.17786), (19.52662, 73.17784), (19.5265, 73.1779)]
>>> len(l)
293
```

I encoded this lat long back using using [this](https://www.daftlogic.com/projects-online-csv-polyline-encoder.htm) online tool to obtain polyline:

```
ezdvBcps}Lt@UBHdAa@K]Wc@}@kAOKhEsGNDf@PhARZBlCA`CIr@Jh@^`@hAVbAD~@B`ELjBJpCJlAXbAd@dAvCbGlA`CbBvCpA`D`AnCVrB\fBf@nB~@vAt@|@XLdDj@hCl@nAf@`DbBdC`B`@b@Xr@lA|DnAvBvB`G\fA^p@j@|@~E~EbBrBxDdFXh@~AtGn@lB^`Bj@rBx@rBv@bBpCoElAH^KZQxB_@j@WR@b@I\MdAo@ZWVI^Eh@Mv@MvDL^I\?RMj@QfAKXMXY`Ae@n@i@vCq@\O|Ck@b@c@ZQZG~AVzAJVALDj@b@LBb@dALRTLx@?R@JF^j@Zs@TQbCq@p@WPc@d@sBJk@b@gA\cAHo@Cq@H}@@q@FGrAgAv@k@|@e@v@k@bAaAdDuB|@c@?cBQcAHWHOFYGcADOr@{@H_@Km@Cg@BW?e@Ca@{@aECu@O{@GmCKm@S{B?{@Ci@a@yB_@{@U_Ao@SIOQqAQq@Ym@[{@@_AK]cAu@w@IOGg@a@g@IWO]Ko@KSIWUUMW_@m@eDCY@_@AYSWw@e@]s@W]SMQUQu@OWWSk@s@SqAEi@WgA?iAIeA[_Ae@i@OSGYMYa@YIQSR[P}@iEFkBAs@Ku@m@k@e@Y_@IqDEcAMgAWoACe@GWQaAgAYk@Si@_@k@[AaC{@pAqA|@mCVaAHk@YmCIQSQOS
```

Now when I tried to visualize this polyline, I got this:

**Image 2**

[image]

This seems exactly the grey path that I get when I search for direction on maps.google.com (grey route in the image below)
([search link](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/19.5271524,+73.1783505/19.5035682,73.1870157/@19.5110317,73.1676902,14z/data=!4m7!4m6!1m3!2m2!1d73.1783505!2d19.5271524!1m0!3e2)):

[image]

Also when I stored above lat long array itself in postgress as `GEOMETRY(POINT)` (as explained in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/257470/199167) answer), QGIS rendered array of points having same shape as above (image2).

Why is polyline1 so different from what I get in maps.google.com and why first converting it to lat-long array and re-encoding it gives polyline2 which is the same as that shown in maps.google.com?

Answer (score 4):

Replace all of the double backslashes (`\\`) in the original with single backslashes (`\`) then try the online decoder again:

```
ezdvBcps}Lt@W@F@BVKl@UK]Wc@}@kAOKBEzA{BdA}Ab@s@LBf@RjARZBv@?rAAfBIX?f@FLBf@^b@hATbAF~@BvB?hALjBHpCLjAVdAd@dAxCbGlA~BbBvCpAbD`AnCVpB\hBf@nB|@tAb@f@RVXLbDj@jCl@nAf@`DbBdC`B`@b@HNN`@lA~DnAvBvB`G\fA^p@j@z@~E`FbBpBxDfFXh@|@pD`@bB^fANd@\`Bl@rBb@fATj@v@bBjBwCd@w@NB^B\@\K\Q|AWZGXOPIRBb@K\Kl@_@VOZWVI^Eh@Ov@KxCJ\@\K^@RMh@QhAMXKXY`@Q^SLK`@]fBc@n@M\OlB_@n@KNMRUZQZGh@Ht@Lx@F`@BTANDRNTPNDDHLXN`@LRTJx@?RBJFFLV\Zs@TQ`@MVIhAYp@YPc@VgALk@Hk@d@eA\cAHq@Eo@J}@@q@DItAgAv@i@|@e@v@k@bAaAdDuB|@c@?I?]?{@Ms@COFWJODYEcABOTU^e@H_@Km@Ci@BU?e@Ca@Ie@e@oBKk@Eu@M{@CoAC}@Km@Iy@IaA?{@Ci@Ms@UgA]y@Mm@GQICe@QKMGi@Gi@GSI[Ym@[{@@_AK]SMo@i@OCg@EOEMMYSi@IUO]Ko@KSIWUWMU_@I]Kw@WoACY@a@CWQWe@[QIOYMYW]SMQUQu@OWWSUWU[SsAEg@Ic@Mc@?a@Ai@Em@AUOa@M_@e@g@MSGYOY_@YIQSR[Pa@mBQaAI[@QDyACq@Iu@o@k@e@Y]IcAAmBC]Ee@IgAUWAw@Ae@GWSaAeAYk@Si@a@k@YAc@O{@]a@MnAqA~@mCVaAHk@YmCIQSQOS
```

A backslash is commonly used as an "escape character", meaning you put it in front of another character that you want to be interpreted literally.  So if you want to have a backslash interpreted literally, you prefix it with another backslash.  That's what Google is doing in the JSON response.

It works when run through the Python module because Python interprets it in the same way, and converts the double backslashes to single before decoding the polyline.  The online tool, however, is not doing this.